# (discord.py) Difference between Client.fetch_channel() and Client.get_channel()

Tags: discord.py

From [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_channel) it says that `fetch_channel` is an API call, and it should return the same thing as `get_channel` (returns the channel).

I tried to use `client.get_channel` to get my dm channel, and it returned None. But after I changed it to `client.fetch_channel`, it worked just fine.

I called them in a `discord.ext.tasks.loop` function (The function will be called every n seconds), like as follows:

```
# this alarmSender() will be called every 10 seconds
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def alarmSender():
    chnl = client.get_channel(dm_channel_id)
    # here chnl == None
    chnl = await client.fetch_channel(dm_channel_id)
    # here chnl == channel object
```

I'm just curious what's the difference between the 2 functions, making them return different things. Any information will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `fetch_channel` fetches the information from the API, makes an API call, `get_channel` gets the channel object from the bots cache. It's suggested to use `get_channel`

Comment: The docs just say one is an API call, the other isn't (unclear what this even means as both are API calls) but `get_channel` should be prefered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `get_channel` isn't working for you is that DM channels are not delivered to you over the Discord gateway upon connecting, whereas guild channels are. When you use `fetch_channel` you're not relying on data that you have to get the channel, but the data that Discord has, which of course includes that DM channel's details.

#### When should you use each?

Generally speaking, there's very rarely a reason you'd need to use `fetch_channel` instead of `get_channel`. If the channel is cached you can use `get_channel`, and provided you have the correct [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents) enabled, all channels in guilds will be cached, in addition to any DM channels where you have either already fetched them, or the user DMs the bot, in which case you will receive the DM channel's details.